# Querying Sesame on local machine using IP address

Tags: javascript, jquery, server, sesame, triplestore

I send queries to a Sesame triplestore and render the results on a webpage. The server is set up on a local computer. Everything works fine when I  access the server from the same computer (say computer A).

If I try to access the triplestore from another computer (say computer B) using computer A's IP address, I get this error:

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

b.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:5b.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ allScans.js:26b.Callbacks.c @ jquery.min.js:3b.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:3b.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:3H @ jquery.min.js:3
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Someone please help. I need to present this soon and can't find a way out. This net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is not specific to Chrome. Firefox doesn't return anything for the queries as well. I've looked at some solutions to net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE but they don't work.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer this, but my guess would be (assuming that you have either jsonp callbacks or CORS headers working properly in principle) that you should have a look at firewall settings and proxy settings on your server. Look in the Apache, Tomcat, and Sesame logs to try and determine where the request stops or where an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nailed the problem on its head, Jeen. The problem was with Windows Firewall. To solve, I had to let Tomcat server communicate through the firewall. This meant creating rules to enable Tomcat.exe in the Apache Folder to be allowed inbound communication (inbound port rule).